# Хитрая ошибка при POST запросе через Curl

Tags: curl, php, синтаксический-анализ

Здравствуйте! Пытаюсь отправить POST форму через curl на данной странице http://www.akparts.ru/searchdetail/. Для примера можете ввести номер 2630035503. При отправке формы через браузер все отлично работает (проверил при отключенном js и почищенных cookies). Необходима всего лишь одна печенька с идентификатором сессии (и curl её получает и передает). Однако при запросе через curl вместо результатов (где перечисленны аналоги для номера) вылазит ошибка "Произошла ошибка на сервере. Попробуйте обновить страницу.
 Если ошибка будет повторяться, обратитесь к менеджеру."

Помогите найти причину проблему. В браузере та же форма с теми же данными прекрасно работает, ajax не нужен (проверял с выключенным js). В чём подвох?

Заранее спасибо.

`$ch = curl_init();
    $url = 'http://www.akparts.ru/searchdetail/';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $f = fopen(dirname(__FILE__).'/headers.txt', "w+"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.akparts.ru/searchdetail/");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux x86_64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.15");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "search=Y&number_list=2630035503&with_change=1&period=&post_type=all&btnSubmit.x=47&btnSubmit.y=11");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,  dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Keep-Alive'));
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $data;
    curl_close($ch);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение:

Открываем фаербаг (или что там у вас), смотрим заголовки запроса, берем куки оттуда.

У меня получилось так (затронул три строки):

```
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'Connection: Keep-Alive',
  'Cookie: SID=p97easr4t17925kgu8jab9smh7'
));
```

[пруф](http://test.sh4dow.ru/9.php) (отключил еще заголовки и всю лишнюю говорильню)

*UPD* исправил, из кук нужен только СИД. Видимо, его-то вы и не передавали)

Comment: Спасибо, подставил свою сессию из браузера и получилось.
Только вот почему cookie не подставлялся? В файле cookie.txt был SID и у меня получалось даже авторизоваться.
Как правильно надо подставить ему куки?

Comment: Подставил cookie в файл cookie.txt, так тоже работает. Почему ему не нравится сессия, которую я получаю через CURL?

Comment: @autostyle, если честно, почему не сохраняет - не в курсе, я просто поюзал самый очевидный путь) Возможно, в файле куков что-то не так - перебитые заголовки, переносы не в том месте, кодировка не та etc; в любом случае, у меня его не было.